# Как вместо чтения из файла, использовать чтение из нескольких textbox?

Tags: c#

Заголовок вопроса не совсем корректный, но я не знаю как обозначить его по другому.

Есть текстовый файл с данными следующего вида:

11.111111 22.222222

33.333333 44.444444

55.555555 66.666666

И есть конструкция, которая вытаскивает эти данные из файла, парсит и кладет в переменную в виде списка:

```
var autoList = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("Price.txt").Select(i => (X: double.Parse(i.Split(' ')[0].Replace(".", ",")), Y: double.Parse(i.Split(' ')[1].Replace(".", ",")))).ToList();
```

Но я хочу отказаться от файла, а вместо него вводить данные в несколько textbox-ов (например 3), куда-то их класть (в список?) и дальше уже использовать конструкцию для парсинга выше. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: **Никогда** не используйте `Replace` для таких случаев. Задайте в методе `Parse` нужную культуру с точкой.

Comment: Вместо текстбоксов используйте `NumericUpDown` для ввода дробных чисел.